# ffmpeg How to get PCM floats from AVFrame with AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an AVFrame obtained through a decoder that has a format of `AVSampleFormat::AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT`. My issue is I want to convert the data stored inside

```
avFrame->data; // returns uint8_t *
```

to Array of floats that are between [-1, +1]. I see that `avFrame->data;` returns `uint8_t *` how may I use this to obtain the float pcm data for each channel of the audio?

I tried the following:

```
auto *floatArrPtr = (float *)(avResampledDecFrame->data[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < avResampledDecFrame->nb_samples; i++) {
        // TODO: store interleaved floats somewhere
        floatArrPtr++;
    }
```

but I am not sure if this is the right way to get data

Comment: You have to cast the data. In the [resampling audio](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/resampling_audio_8c-example.html)  example, they do the same (e.g. fill_samples fn). Just to be clear, the decoded format is FMT_FLT, that is basically what you want, the only reason is the pointer type, right?

Comment: I setted up a resampler I get the output as FMT_FLT. I edited my question, can you check if it makes sense?

Comment: The cast seems ok (c-cast), but according to [AVFrame::nb_samples](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.7/structAVFrame.html#a02f45ab8191aea1660159f1e464237ea) _'number of audio samples (per channel)'_ and as an example, which comes the closest to your example [print_frame](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.7/filtering_audio_8c-example.html#a69).

Comment: I forgot to multiply by number of channels since the data is packed. It worked afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for the info, i myself wasn't sure about that, now 'we' know.

Comment: yes indeed, thank you for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
auto *floatArrPtr = (float *)(avResampledDecFrame->data[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < avResampledDecFrame->nb_samples * avResampledDecFrame->channels; i++) {
        // TODO: do as you please with data
        floatArrPtr[i];
    }
```